# Send two parameters to php file htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am making a dynamic php page. What content the page should load is decided by a GET request through the .htaccess file. If i write `/page/groups/admin_users` then the real request would be `index.php?page=groups/admin_users`. This works a sharm, the problem is when i want to do an additional GET requests. 

I want to be able to send `/page/groups/admin_users?id=1` and really request `index.php?page=/groups/admin_users&id=1`. When i try this `$_GET['page'];` has a value but `$_GET['id'];` is blank.

Here is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine  on

# Tidy up adresses
RewriteRule    ^page/?$    /index.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^page([\w-/]+)/?$    /index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

I have tryed to include only letters numbers and "/" but it still wont go through.

If this is very hard or not possible i could of course make it a part of the scope. Like `/page/groups/admin_users/id/1` and "decode" it with the PHP script. It would be a lot more convenient to just send two parameters tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag will combine current URL query strings with those defined in the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page([\w-/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```